# Run Script on form submit

Tags: php, forms, execute

I've been looking around for this and am really confused, there are similar questions but I can't seem to make any of them work. So I apologize if this has been repeated before. Here's my problem, I need to run a php script on form submit instead of re-directing to that page. Here's my code:
Form:

```
<form action="comments.php" method="post">
  <div id="comment-input">
    <input type="text" name="subjectField" id="subjectField" 
           placeholder="Subject (optional)">
  </div>
  <div id="comment-textarea">
    <textarea name="messageField" required id="messageField" cols="39" rows="4" 
              placeholder="Your Message (required)"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="comment-submit">
    <div>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Post Comment"
             class="comment-submit small button green">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Comments.php:**

```
<?php   
    $fileNameHere = 'filenamehere.php';
    $hits[0] ++;

    $fileNameHereFileHandle = fopen($fileNameHere, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
    $subjectField = $_POST['subjectField'];
    $messageField = $_POST['messageField'];
    $savestring = '' . $hits[0] .'';
    fputs($fileNameHereFileHandle, $savestring);
    fclose($fileNameHereFileHandle);
?>
```

**filenamehere.php**

Empty.

Hopefully this was clear, please help me out if you can, I would really appreciate it. Again, thank you.

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this? If you're looking to submit data without reloading the page, you should consider looking at using jQuery and AJAX instead.

Comment: You're looking for a way to run server side code, without leaving the page you're on?

Comment: If you put the **Comments.php** code on the same page as the form, then remove the action, it should post to the same page.

Comment: Upful you're right, thanks very much and sorry for the confusion :) The code wont make sense now I'm still learning :)